# When are audio threads preempted?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, real-time

In audio threads, I've been told it's good style to not use syscalls like e.g. `printf()` because they give control back to the kernel, which can then decide to continue with another thread, which means your audio thread can lose a lot of time. I found the idiom strange because modern Linux kernels could still interrupt the audio thread (preemption). Maybe, however, there's no (or very limited) preemption if the audio thread has RT prio...

Does Linux prempt a thread if all other running threads have lower priority?

Is the behaviour different between realtime and non-realtime kernels?

Comment: If the `printf` call leads to a synchronous `write` and the thread blocks because the CPU has to wait for I/O, then the thread is preempted and some other thread is run (if available). The OS will not let the CPU sit on its hands when there is work to be done.

Comment: As soon as the I/O is finished, will the realtime job get its control back by the kernel preempting other jobs?

Comment: Yes, if the real-time thread wakes up (changes state to runnable) and a lower-priority thread is running on a CPU (or a CPU is idle), then the real-time thread gets the CPU and starts running again. So the thread is only blocked as long as the `write` takes to return, unless there is some other real-time thread with *equal priority*, which is scheduled instead. The Linux kernel does not preempt a running thread if all other threads have lower priority.

Comment: But then, why should one avoid syscalls in general? From what you say, only the waiting time matters, because the rt thread will get back control immediatelly. It's clear that `printf` will take some time for IO. But what about e.g. mutex locking? That should not cause IO wait time...